# How to create custom popup in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to create a custom popup like screencast.[image]

Comment: Your're welcome. What keeps you from doing this?

Comment: I want add a pop with button click

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Are you sure you are the first person in the world to achieve this or might google help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup). It is quite popular open source project which you can use as a reference to learn.